# Prevent Github Action workflow from running on pull requests

Tags: github, workflow, github-actions

This is the first workflow I'm writing with Github Actions, I am using this worfklow combined with AWS CodeDeploy to automate deployment.

```
# .github/workflows/deployment.yml

on:
    push:
        branches:
            - Production

jobs:
    deploy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            -   uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
                with:
                    aws-access-key-id: //AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                    aws-secret-access-key: //AWS_SECRET_KEY
                    aws-region: // region
            -   uses: actions/checkout@v2
            -   id: deploy
                uses: webfactory/create-aws-codedeploy-deployment@v0.2.2
            -   uses: peter-evans/commit-comment@v1
                with:
                    token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
                    body: |
                        @${{ github.actor }} this was deployed as [${{ steps.deploy.outputs.deploymentId }}](https://console.aws.amazon.com/codesuite/codedeploy/deployments/${{ steps.deploy.outputs.deploymentId }}?region=eu-central-1) to group `${{ steps.deploy.outputs.deploymentGroupName }}`.
```

Everything is working perfectly when I push new commits to the branch "Production" but the problem is that with every new pull request to merge feature branches into the "dev" branch , Github runs checks on the pull requests and executes the workflow, which is not needed or written in its code.

Comment: You can add on the branches list a `- '!dev'` to prevent the workflow to trigger on this specific branch. There is a `branches-ignore` option as well (reference: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#on)

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause. In previous commmits, I had the worfklow written with the event **on pull request** and feature branches that are still not up to date with the workflow.yml still use the old version which has the "on pull request event trigger".